# Checkbox placement issue while filtering data in protected worksheet excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a protected worksheet, with cell protection as both Locked and Hidden. In first column I have Check Box (Form Control) against each row.

[image: Unfiltered Data]

Problem is when I try to filter data, there is a extra check box in last row. 
[image: Filtered Data]

I tried linking cell to check box and enabled option 'Move but don't size with cells' but still behavior is same. Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: Does the same happen if worksheet is NOT protected?

Comment: @RyszardJędraszyk Yes

Comment: show your code up to now

Comment: @DisplayName Right now its just from excel itself, haven't wrote in any vba code so far. Tried using Activex checkbox but same behaviour, and more bugy (like checking un-checking doesn't work if filter is applied and reset). Seems like have to do some sort of re-positioning of shape, still working :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well seems like checkboxes are bad guys

but there's a prison even for them

- make sure your sheet has at least one  cell that calculates
- make sure each checkbox is *completely* inside its cell, i.e. its
  borders (which appear at selecting it) must *entirely* fall within the cell
  where you chose it to be
- set your sheet calculation as "automatic" (Formulas->Calculation Option-> Automatic)
- place the following code in the sheet code pane

  ```
  Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
      Dim shp As Shape

      For Each shp In Me.Shapes
          shp.Visible = shp.TopLeftCell.EntireRow.Height <> 0
      Next
  End Sub
  ```